# How to extract an array of one cell from a CSV in powershell

Tags: powershell

im spanish, so sorry for my language. In first place i want to say how useful was for me this page, and be grateful with all of members.
I would like do a question:
I export a CSV to a $x, that CSV content in his first cell next:
"one","two","three"    the headboard of csv is "aaa";"bbb"
the separated is ";"

```
-Code:
     $x = Import-Csv c:\test.csv -Delimiter ';'
     $x
     aaa                                      bbb
     -------                                  -------   
     "one","two","three"                      ttttt
```

now load the first cell to another variable

```
-Code:
  $y = $x[0].aaa
  $y
  "one","two","three"
```

the idea is that the new variable "$y" contains a value type array, but it's doesn't work.

anyone have idea how is possible do something like that?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When importing from CSV `"one","two","three"` is a literal string, not an array. You have to split it yourself.

Example, split by `,`  and remove double quotes:

```
$x[0].aaa -split ',' | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '"',''}
```

or

```
$x[0].aaa.Split(',') | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '"',''}
```

Reference:

- [Powershell split() vs -split - what's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796959/powershell-split-vs-split-whats-the-difference)

Comment: $x[0].aaa  can't work, because it returns the value with the key "aaa" form the first [0] item of $x.

Comment: is perfect, it's what i was looking for, extract an ARRAY since a CSV cell. did not know the split function, i go to study more information about that.

One more time thanks for your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

beatcracker has the correct answer.

Just to give another exmaple, you can also clean up the quotes using Trim()

```
$x[0].aaa.Split(",") | ForEach-Object {$_.Trim('"')}
```

Comment: Totally forgot about `.Trim()`, it's way more proper to use it in this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about ...

```
$y = @((Import-Csv c:\test.csv -Delimiter ';').aaa)
#  or
$x = Import-Csv c:\test.csv -Delimiter ';'
$y = @($x.aaa)
```

To check the type do this ...

```
($y.GetType()).BaseType.Name
```

Get-Member does not work on arrays, it shows you the type of the array items.  In the current case it would return [string].

```
$y | Get-Member  # WRONG !!!
```

Comment: at first, try to convert an array with this method, but it was impossible to segregate the words in a variable.