# Split Using String Without Keeping Deliminator

Tags: powershell

I have `$String = "part 1 - part 2 - part 3 - part 4"`

I'd like to break it apart on " - " and not keep the deliminator.

I had a hard time figuring out how to split it with a string, but I was able to do it using:

`$P1, $P2, $P3, $P4 = $String - Split "(?= - )"`

$P1 is fine, but $P2, $P3, and $P4 all start with " - ".

Is there a way to prevent the deliminator from being included? My understanding is I would just remove the quotes to prevent it from being included, but then the split doesn't work.

Comment: ``-split ' - '``

Comment: I thought -split ' - ' was the same as .split(' - ') so I didn't try the first since the latter one didn't work. Your answer works but why is it different than .split(' - ')?

Comment: Nope, see the discussed details here: -split operator vs .split method.  ---  https://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/Powershell_split_operator#The_String_Method_.Split.28.29

Answer (score 0):

$string = $P1, $P2, $P3, $P4

$string.split('-')

call each section like this $string[0] , $string[1], $string[2], $string[3]

Comment: That would cause issues with things like `part 1 is a state-of-the-art design - part 2 - part 3 - part 4`. The spaces next to the dash is important.

Comment: you could use regex $string.split('\s+-\s+')

Comment: Nope. Check `$string.split('\s+-\s+') | ForEach-Object { "[$_]" }`: the .Net `System.String.Split` method [does not understand regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23797329/3439404).